# How to install plugin to grafana installed by Google Click to Deploy containers

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grafana

I deployed prometheus and grafana to my kubernetes cluster using Google Click to Deploy containers - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/prometheus - now I would like to add plugin to the grafana dashboard. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are done with the installation and setup from the marketplace you can simply connect to GKE kubernetes cluster and get Pods.

List down all pods based on namespace:

```
kubectl get pods
```

SSH into grafana or prometheus in which you want to install the plugin

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- /bin/bash
```

also for grafan might require to update the environment variable

Adding an environment variable **GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS**=grafana-piechart-panel,grafana-clock-panel will install the plugins for you

Comment: I did what you told me and it said that I needed to restart grafana. I tried `service grafana-server restart` and it showed `grafana-server: unrecognized service`. How to fix it ?